# Enzyme Mock ToastAndroid React Native Component

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a react native component that uses ToastAndroid Component in a method, and while testing with enzyme I keep getting error `TypeError: _reactNative.ToastAndroid.show is not a function`

I am using `react-native-mock-renderer` for jest mock and my component has a method that gets called in with an onPress handler.

```js
 validateAndProceed = () => {
    ToastAndroid.show(
        'Show toast',
        ToastAndroid.SHORT,
      );
  };
```

and my test to verify

```js
it('should validate and process', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component
    />);
    const instance = wrapper.dive().instance();
    jest.spyOn(instance, 'validateAndProceed');
    instance.validateAndProceed();
    expect(instance.validateAndProceed).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I created a custom mock for the ToastAndroid

```js
const ToastAndroid = {
  SHORT: '',
  LONG: '',

  TOP: '',
  BOTTOM: '',
  CENTER: '',

  show: jest.fn(),
  showWithGravity: jest.fn(),
  showWithGravityAndOffset: jest.fn(),
};

module.exports = ToastAndroid;
```

Still a not working

Comment: You can try mocking it this way in your jest setup file: `jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Components/ToastAndroid/ToastAndroid', () => {
  return {
    show: jest.fn,
  };
});`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mock the entire module. Mocking only relevant functions and constants did it for me.

Example:

```
ToastAndroid.showWithGravity = jest.fn();
ToastAndroid.show = jest.fn();
```